# Integrating Firebase admin with Angular 4 project

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-admin

Trying to add firebase-admin to my angular project but getting error that I just cannot get around (see screenshot)

[image: here]

Did `npm install google-cloud` but that resulted in just more errors
(coming from android and trying to figure out by my own but here I'm missing something and don't know exactly what)

My `app.component.ts`:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent {
 constructor() {
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = 
require("C:/Users/Pawel/Desktop/CODE/pamiAdmin3/src/app/serviceKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://pami-16c0f.firebaseio.com'
  });
 }
 }
```

Comment: The admin SDK is only for use on a server, and is not for end-user access (see the warning at the top of the [Add the Firebase Admin SDK to your Server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) page).

Comment: @Jeff well that's gona be a server page ...:S

Comment: The Admin SDK is for use only in a trusted server environment - like a Node.JS server that you control. Giving select users more access to view/change things in your DB should be accomplished through database security rules

Comment: Because Angular is a front-end service anyone that has access to the site can get your service Key. This isn't the way firebase-admin should be used.

Comment: @sketchthat -so the reason for that error is beacause I'm using angular? should I make an api using node.js and then connect that to  my angular site that administrates users-is that the correct way to do that?

Comment: Thats correct, because it's only meant to be run on a secure-server, not a public interfacing website.

Comment: did you found a workaround or  do you know how to begin ?Im stuck same as you I have a angular admin page where its only accessible by admin using  username and password so you need to authenticate so how should I proceed ?

Comment: @user3277530 well in my case I used Firebase functions and just put an Http request(in angular)  to the code in my firebase funcions with the respons that I need in my angular admin

Comment: @user3277530 but just to log into your application as an admin I would just use firebase with the node like "role":"admin" so that after your FirebaseAuth U go into the "role" node and check if the role is "admin" and from there it akes U to the wanted space- but if U want to  f.ex. create users from your admin space then U have to do it by using f.ex firebase functions like mentioned at the begining

Comment: @pb4now the users in my admin app authentication already works , the problem is I thought I can import the nodejs fcm admin code in my angular project on my aws s3 like I did with my angular but It looks like I need to use lambda to run the fcm admin code on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement you admin API using Node.js and `firebase-admin`, and then deploy it in a server. Then your Angular app can connect to it when it needs to perform some admin function. Pass the ID token from Angular app to the server, where it can be verified using the Admin SDK to make sure that the caller has the required admin privileges.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this instead on deploying it on example on angular in AWS S3 website I need to add it on AWS Lambda  because s3 is accessible ?